Alternative to selfcontrol.app on IOS
On my MacOS I use selfcontrol.app to block a website. Selfcontrol.app blocks the website in the entire network by using hosts. Is there an alternative to that on IOS?
An app that I cannot delete or edit until the time is out and it blocks websites on the entire network. My phone is supervised so a profile alternative would also suffice.
Thanks.
